# what wrong with my mySQL query using REGEX and or operator?

Tags: mysql, regex

I have a script that is generating queries like this one by grabbing categories and keywords from the database. However something is wrong with the syntax it seems. here is the code first:

```
UPDATE `mrhowtos_main`.`eng-jap` SET `category` = 'travel' WHERE `eng` REGEXP 'abroad|country|sight seeing|foreign|plane|train|bus' and where `category` REGEXP 'misc|none';
```

and here is the error returned by mySQL:

## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'where `category` REGEXP 'misc|none'' at line 1

I have looked at it for a long time and still dont seem to see what is wrong with it. im certain the error is not in the table or column names in the DB.

Answer (score 2):

The second `where` shouldn't be there. Try:

```
UPDATE `mrhowtos_main`.`eng-jap` SET `category` = 'travel' WHERE `eng` REGEXP 'abroad|country|sight seeing|foreign|plane|train|bus' and `category` REGEXP 'misc|none';
```

Comment: bingo! but the funny thing is, im sure i tried that already, but maybe that was when something else was wrong with it, any way. thanks.

Comment: @user1397417 Please remember to accept this answer when you have a chance, thanks!